# C# Oracle Rest API, Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, oracle, rest

I am trying to use Ocacle's Financial REST API and I'm having trouble making it work in C# in VS2019.

I can confirm the restful call works using Postman, so I know my credentials are fine but I must be missing something trying this with in code.

So URL is like so:
http://MYCLOUDDOMAIN/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/ledgerBalances?finder=AccountBalanceFinder;accountCombination=3312-155100-0000-0000-0000-00000,accountingPeriod=Feb-20,currency=USD,ledgerSetName=Ledger,mode=Detail&fields=LedgerName,PeriodName,Currency,DetailAccountCombination,Scenario,BeginningBalance,PeriodActivity,EndingBalance,AmountType,CurrencyType,ErrorDetail

So I stick that in postman, put in my credentials (basic auth) and it works find. In VS I've tried both the RestSharp way and basic HTTPRequest way as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/ledgerBalances?finder=AccountBalanceFinder;accountCombination=3312-155100-0000-0000-0000-00000,accountingPeriod=Feb-20,currency=USD,ledgerSetName=Ledger US,mode=Detail&fields=LedgerName,PeriodName,Currency,DetailAccountCombination,Scenario,BeginningBalance,PeriodActivity,EndingBalance,AmountType,CurrencyType,ErrorDetail");
        r.Method = "GET";

        string auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Username" + ":" + "Password"));
        r.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + " " + auth);
        r.ContentType = "application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourcecollection+json";

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse())
        {
            int b = 0;
        }
```

RestSharp:

```
            var client = new RestClient("http://MYCLOUDDOMAIN/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/ledgerBalances?finder=AccountBalanceFinder;accountCombination=3312-155100-0000-0000-0000-00000,accountingPeriod=Feb-20,currency=USD,ledgerSetName=Ledger US,mode=Detail&fields=LedgerName,PeriodName,Currency,DetailAccountCombination,Scenario,BeginningBalance,PeriodActivity,EndingBalance,AmountType,CurrencyType,ErrorDetail");
        client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator("UserName", "Password");

        //Tried authorization this way as well.
        //JObject AuthRequest = new JObject();
        //AuthRequest.Add("Username", "UserName");
        //AuthRequest.Add("Password", "Password");

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.GET;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        //request.AddParameter("text/json", AuthRequest.ToString(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourcecollection+json");
        request.AddHeader("REST-Framework-Version", "1");
        var response = client.Get(request);
```

No matter what I try I am always 401 not authorized. I suspect its some kind of header thing? I can't see the raw request header in postman

I am new to REST. I am used to using WSDLs soap services.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
     var result = await client.GetAsync("url");
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.

In postman, it was fine with the URL I posted being HTTP but in C# code it was not. I switched the URL to HTTPS and it started working just fine.